# Reactor Flux remains blocks till getting response from server

Tags: spring-boot, mono, spring-webflux, project-reactor, flux

I'v created a Flux which emits API response on subscription. The API takes few seconds to respond. I'm also switching the flow to a sceduler with 2 threads.

```
private Scheduler sc = Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(2, Integer.MAX_VALUE, "newwww-sch");

Flux.just(i)
        .flatMap(x -> {
          try {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Do Request " + i);
            return Mono.just(spectrumAvailabilityApi.getSpectrumAvailability(spectrumAvailabilityRequest));
          } catch (ApiException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
        })
    .subscribeOn(sc)
    .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Got Response " + i));
```

When I trigger the flow using paraller threads, I notice it submits 2 requests and then does nothing till it gets response from server for atleast one of the requests.

```
newwww-sch-1 Do Request 11
newwww-sch-2 Do Request 12
newwww-sch-2 Got Response 12
newwww-sch-1 Got Response 11
newwww-sch-2 Do Request 13
newwww-sch-1 Do Request 14
newwww-sch-1 Got Response 14
newwww-sch-2 Got Response 13
```

Also, the thread submitting the request is the same thread processing the response of the request. Is this expected? My expectation was that it will submit the requests as long as the scheduler threads are available or the threads are waiting for the response from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using blocking OkHttpClient for making the API calls, as a result the thread remains blocked and cannot take more request. To solve it, I switched to non-blocking Spring WebClient which returns a Mono.

```
private WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
    .baseUrl("https://demo.com/api/demo")
    .defaultHeader("Authorization", token)
    .defaultHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .defaultHeader("Accept", "application/json")
    .build();
UriSpec<RequestBodySpec> uriSpec = webClient.post();

RequestHeadersSpec<?> responseMono = uriSpec.uri("/v1/demo")
    .body(Mono.just(demoRequest), DemoRequest.class)
    .header("Content-Type", APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    .accept(MediaType.valueOf(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
    .header("Authorization", token);

return responseMono.retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(DemoResponse.class);
```

Using WebClient I was able to perform non-blocking IO and threads were not blocked for server response.

```
newwww-sch-1 Do Request 11
newwww-sch-2 Do Request 12
newwww-sch-2 Do Request 13
newwww-sch-1 Do Request 14
newwww-sch-2 Got Response 12
newwww-sch-1 Got Response 11
newwww-sch-1 Got Response 14
newwww-sch-2 Got Response 13
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right that it submits as long as you have scheduler threads, but your scheduler has two threads, that's why you only two in parallel.

You specified the thread for subscription with `.subscribeOn(sc)` it's used for submission, and since you didn't specify anything else for internal `flatMap` subscription it reuses the existing thread. If you want to separate them, and also increase the threads count used for actual request subscribe to it on another scheduler, like:

```
.flatMap(x -> 
      Mono.fromCallable {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Do Request " + i);
        return spectrumAvailabilityApi.getSpectrumAvailability(spectrumAvailabilityRequest);
      }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
)
```

One of the issues, btw, is that your `flatMap` is blocking because it waits for  `spectrumAvailabilityApi.getSpectrumAvailability(spectrumAvailabilityRequest)` execution.

Comment: You mean spectrumAvailabilityApi.getSpectrumAvailability(spectrumAvailabilityRequest) is a blocking call and not pure IO? It's an OkHttpClient execute call. My main issue is why it's blocking? when we talk about non-blocking IO is this what we should expect?

Comment: Because after calling the method the thread waits for the returned value. A non-blocking method returns a `Mono` or other `Publisher`

Comment: For a reactive (i.e., non-blocking) HTTP you can use the Reactor Netty project https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#http-client

Comment: I get it now, the call spectrumAvailabilityApi.getSpectrumAvailability(spectrumAvailabilityRequest) is a blocking call, as a result it blocks the Scheduler thread. It call should return a Publisher.

Comment: Yes. Though internally it may effectively use the threads for IO your thread still waits for a result. Netty is good for IO because it's non-blocking by nature, but to effectively use it you need another way to get a notification of incoming data, not just a method return value. In terms of Reactor is should be a Publisher, i.e., it's returned immediately but the actual data may come later, so it doesn't block the current thread.

Comment: Thanks, let me try few things and come back.